# Memtest throws same error after replacing memory module. MB issue?

Tags: memory, memtest86+

I received a faulty computer with weird errors. My suspicion was a bad memory and after running memtest it found a lot of errors as soon as I started it (around the 1504th MB).

Bought a new one and run memtest on it too. Now it only started failing at 7th test around address 129MB. I even tried the other slot to exclude a MB error but the errors were exactly the same.

Returned and replaced the fresh but faulty ram with a new one and the new one produced exactly the same errors at the same address. On both slots.

To me it seems a motherboard issue but could any of you please elaborate? Has something similar happened to you before?

Comment: any bad (bulging or leaking) capacitors on the motherboard?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few options here:

1. You have bought RAM that doesn't match your Motherboards' needs (unlikely though worth mentioning).
2. Either you are extremely unlucky an you have yet once again received broken RAM sticks.
3. As you already said; your Motherboard is broken.

Personally I think your Motherboard is broken (or atleast something is wrong with it).
I do understand from you post you have already done this, but if not I suggest you do the following (taken from [here](http://smallbusiness.chron.com/there-way-test-motherboards-memory-slots-69847.html)):

It would be the best to use a new RAM stick and ask the shop  you buy it/someone else to test it for you to be 100% sure its a functioning stick.

> Open your computer and check the slots through trial and error. The only way to check your motherboard's memory slots is to place a working RAM stick into each one and see if your machine boots properly. Remove all RAM sticks and place one you know is functional into the first slot on your motherboard. Boot your computer. If it starts without problems, you know that stick and that slot are good. Power down and move the stick to the next slot. Repeat this process until you find the slot that causes a boot failure. You may want to try your other RAM sticks in the same process, starting with the first slot again. Boot with each remaining RAM in the suspected bad slot to verify that the slot has indeed failed. This also verifies that the remaining RAM is good and not adding to your computer's memory problems.

If all slots fail, your motherboard is broken.

Comment: This was the first and most helpful comment so I'll mark it as the answer. Just for giggles: I tried it with a different MB/Proc setting and there was still an error at the 129th MB with memtest. The only solution is that the memtest itself is bugged somehow (it was from an older Ubuntu 12 DVD). I changed back to the old MB and to a new Memory. I'm running stress tests on it and it's working fine so far. Thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

The Dutch Man covered all issues except one.
Check if ALL memory slots are physically free of dust. Use compressed air for that. If the machine is dirty inside this may be the issue.